# showing error cordova.inAppBrowser is undefined

Tags: android, inappbrowser

My application was working fine.

Yesterday I installed SQLite plugin in my app, then suddenly inappbrowser plugin stops working.

When I run the project it says, open of undefined error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Also add refrence in config.xml file in res folder

Answer (score 0):

Check your cordova_plugin.js file.  Whether inAppBrowser is defined there or not.  If not define it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16247469)

Comment: Please ask Tarun whether it helps him or not? If not then we can delete it